# Vscode open file with "ctrl-click" with relative paths

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a `.yaml` file that has a key value pair, the value being a string with a note saying `see <filepath>.yaml`

I want to be able to "ctrl-click" on the file to open it, and this works with absolute paths e.g.: `See file:///c:/dev/<rest of path>/<file>.yaml`

Is this possible with relative paths? How is vscode treating the root folder? Can I set a root folder for `file:///` to look for first?

Comment: in HTML relative paths work, so the click provider for YAML needs adjusting

Comment: So it's the yaml extension causing it not to work? How would it be able to be adjusted?

Comment: in the source code find the `registerDocumentLinkProvider` and inspect the code of the `DocumentLinkProvider`

Answer (score 0):

Relative links work just fine in VsCode as of 2023 version 1.73.1, you just have to get the format right:

```
file://./dir_in_current_directory_of_this_file/filename.yaml
```

Note that you only want 2 slashes for the file protocol, as the third slash would indicate you're starting with an absolute url-